# CodeIgniter encrypted key at the url with Auto Crumb helper

Tags: codeigniter, helper

I use auto CodeIgniter 2.1 + Auto Crumb helper that I get [from here](https://bitbucket.org/ardinotow/autocrumb/)

[image: screenshot]

For example my link to edit contact page is `http://localhost/caster/contact/edit_contact/13/213bcf`

**13** is the contact id and **213bcf** is the **encrypted contact** id to prevent user from just change the contact id from the url.

So my Breadcrumb now display invalid url as in the picture above. The desired breadcrumb would be `Contact \ Edit Contact`. How do I fix or prevent this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's a bug (or perhaps it's by design but it'd seem silly to be as such) with the autocrumb helper which means that regex pattern replacements aren't run unless the particular segment has a hyphen (`-`) or an underscore (`_`) in it.

Normally using the config variable `$config['strip_regexp']` would be sufficient for your requirements here but alas, not in this case.

In this case (assuming there wont me more parameters on the end of the URL), you can do the following:

```
$ci = get_instance();
if( preg_match( '#\d+/[a-z0-9]+$#i', $ci->uri->uri_string() ) ) {
    $config['exclude_segment'] = $config['exclude_segment'] + array(
        $total = $ci->uri->total_segments(),
        $total-1
    );
}
```

This should be inserted just underneath `$config['exclude_segment'] = array();` in the `app/config/breadcrumb.php` file which basically says if URL ends with `numbers/letter-number-pattern` then remove the last two segments of the URL from the breadcrumb.

It's less than ideal but the bug will need fixing first. Obviously this assumes your URL structure won't change. You can add additional conditionals into the `if` to ensure it only occurs on the pages you want.

Comment: thanks. I though there is proper way without hacking the helpers, but I guess I will settle this method first until they comeout with the bug fix.